# Cannot figure out why my Powershell script is getting permission errors

Tags: powershell

I cannot figure out why im getting permission errors, even though im running the script as a Domain Admin, which is in the full control group on the files/folders im trying to delete. UAC is not enabled on the pc the script is running from. I get the same errors no matter if i use enter-PSsession to the file server itself.

Its got to be how i approached the solution...ive tried other scripts that im not experienced enough to edit, they used a try/catch method with get-wmiobject and then .delete() command, and that script worked great...with no permission problems, it deletes profiles like a charm...and thats with the same credentials as my homemade script...So i really feel its not a true credential problem, and more to do with a shortcoming of the way im using the remove-item cmdlet.

here is my script...its my first homemade, not copy/pasted script, so feel free to point out the obvious bad practices... here is the script, and the errors will be below. The way i wrote this script is to try each individual command separately, then tie them together, that may be why some of it may be redundant.

```
##This process deletes ntuser.dat files and user profile folders


$users = (Read-Host "Enter each user (separate with comma)").split(',') | % {$_.trim()}


foreach ($user in $users) {

$datfile = "ntuser.dat"
$servers = Get-Content C:\servers.txt
$path1 = "\\fileserver\d$\TSEProfiles\$user.DOMAIN"
$path2 = "\\fileserver\d$\TSEProfiles\$user.DOMAIN.V2"


## Checks for ntuser.dat file in specified folders, if true, delete.

## Checking 4 locations on fileserver
If (Test-Path \\fileserver\d$\TSEProfiles\$user.DOMAIN\$datfile){
    Remove-Item $path1\$datfile -recurse -force
    }
if (Test-Path \\fileserver\d$\TSEProfiles\$user.DOMAIN.V2\$datfile){
    Remove-Item $path2\$datfile -recurse -force
    }
If (Test-Path \\fileserver\d$\roamingprofiles\$user.DOMAIN\$datfile){
    Remove-Item $path1\$datfile -recurse -force
    }
If (Test-Path \\fileserver\d$\roamingprofiles\$user.DOMAIN.V2\$datfile){
    Remove-Item $path2\$datfile -recurse -force
    }

## Checking 8 locations, if true, delete. 
foreach ($server in $servers) {

If (Test-Path \\$server\c$\users\$user -PathType Container){
    Remove-Item \\$server\c$\users\$user -recurse -force
            }
        }      
   }




Remove-Item : Access to the path '\\APPS3\c$\users\realdomainuser\AppData\Local\Application Data' is denied.

At C:\Users\admin\Documents\zoink.ps1:35 char:2

+     Remove-Item \\$server\c$\users\$user -recurse -force

+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (\\APPS3\c$\users\realdomainuser:String) [Remove-Item], UnauthorizedAccessException

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemoveItemUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand



Remove-Item : Access to the path '\\APPS4\c$\users\realdomainuser\AppData\Local\Application Data' is denied.

At C:\Users\admin\Documents\zoink.ps1:35 char:2

+     Remove-Item \\$server\c$\users\$user -recurse -force

+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (\\APPS4\c$\users\realdomainuser:String) [Remove-Item], UnauthorizedAccessException

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemoveItemUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
```

django - THis is the delete profile output after running the local machine policy script. still getting auth errors.

```
Remove-Item : Access to the path '\\APPS7\c$\users\someuser\AppData\Local\Application Data' is denied.
At C:\Users\admin\Documents\zoink.ps1:35 char:2
+     Remove-Item \\$server\c$\users\$user -recurse -force
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (\\APPS7\c$\users\someuser:String) [Remove-Item], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemoveItemUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
```

Answer (score 0):

I once was having issues running scripts due to permissions  on some of our Citrix VM's that didn't have powershell scripts running, however I was able to run bat files so I created a PS scripted wrapped inside a bat file.

```
echo "Killing IE"
powershell -Command "stop-process -processname iexplore"
```

While it is nowhere near an elegant solution it is an easy hack that serves it's purpose.

Answer (score -1):

Try running this script.  This is an example of permanently setting your local machine policy for scripts:

```
# SetExecutionPolicyToRemoteSigned.ps1
Write-Output "Setting local Powershell policy to RemoteSigned"
Write-Output ""
Set-ExecutionPolicy -scope CurrentUser Undefined -Force
#Set-ExecutionPolicy -scope Process Undefined -Force
Set-ExecutionPolicy -scope LocalMachine Undefined -Force
Set-ExecutionPolicy -scope CurrentUser RemoteSigned -Force
#Set-ExecutionPolicy -scope Process RemoteSigned -Force
Set-ExecutionPolicy -scope LocalMachine RemoteSigned -Force
Write-Output "Finished."
Get-ExecutionPolicy -list
Start-Sleep -s 10
```

It will result in the following output:

```
PS C:\Users\qa> Get-ExecutionPolicy -list
Scope            ExecutionPolicy
-----            ---------------                                              
MachinePolicy    Undefined
UserPolicy       Undefined
Process          RemoteSigned
CurrentUser      RemoteSigned
LocalMachine     RemoteSigned
```

Then, you can just run a script like this one without a policy prompt.  Best of all, the policy should survive rebooting your system :

```
# Filename: Hello.ps1
Write-Host
Write-Host 'Hello World!'
Write-Host "Good-bye World! `n"
# end of script
```

And another example of running a script:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoLogo -NonInteractive -NoProfile 
    -WindowStyle Hidden -File script_name
```

Comment: what is that script doing exactly? elevating scripts i run here on my pc, to remote computers? i ran the first script but my process scope came back as undefined. Also, i tried to rerun this above script, and got another access error.

Comment: @Dogbyte- NO! RemoteSigned means your system can run scripts created by you locally but NOT ones downloaded from the internet.  This script is really just an example.  You should adjust it to your own purpose.  If you read between the lines here and interpolate a little, my answer will solve your problem.

Comment: Ok well the script im having trouble with was made by me.

Comment: @Dogbyte - Not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: It means I set my machine policy to run remotesigned  and I still get the errors.